# Looking for a CheckedListBox control with icons support

Tags: c#, user-interface, controls, checkedlistbox

Is there a CheckedListBox control with icons support for Windows Forms? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you use a `ListView` control with the `View` property set to `Details` and the `CheckBoxes` property set to `True`?

Comment: Details didn't work, but SmallIcon did. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we use the dev express controls and they have this feature:

http://www.devexpress.com/

Comment: Yes, not free. But not very expensive and it is such a productivity booster. Also note that you only need a license for design time. Oh, and they have quite a lot of free basic controls, so it is worth a visit.